# Error to create a Databricks datasource using Power BI Rest API

Tags: azure-databricks, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-rest-api

I successfuly used the "Gateways - Create Datasource" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/gateways/create-datasource) method from Power BI Rest API to create a SQL datasource, but I´m stuck when I try to create a Databricks datasource.

I saw that there is no Databricks datasource kind, but it could be possible to use the kind "Extension". So a try this code:

OBS: I generated the credential part using the data gateway publick key and a Databricks key.

What am I missing, or doing wrong?

````
{
    "datasourceName": "Databricks AIDA Teste",
    "datasourceType":"Extension",
         "connectionDetails":{
            "path":"{\"host\":\"adb-xxx.azuredatabricks.net\",\"httpPath\":\"\\/sql\\/1.0\\/warehouses\\/xxx\"}",
            "kind":"Databricks"
         },
    "credentialDetails": {
        "credentialType": "Key",
        "credentials": "xxx",
        "privacyLevel": "Organizational"
    }
}```


{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Bad Request",
        "details": [
            {
                "message": "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'connectionDetails', line 4, position 30.",
                "target": "datasourceToGatewayRequest.connectionDetails"
            },
            {
                "message": "'datasourceToGatewayRequest' is a required parameter",
                "target": "datasourceToGatewayRequest"
            }
        ]
    }
}
````

Many thanks!